# Having trouble showing pictures in email send with sendinblue

Tags: image, sendinblue

We've been using sendinblue recently and i've managed to be able to set everyhing up and send emails using my own C# program. In the email I have a link to an image with a  tag.

Whenever these emails are send internally for testing I always get the text "Click here to download pictures. To help protect your privacy, Outlook prevented automatic download of some pictures in this message".

The idea is that the messages we send from sendinblue are to be send as one of our customer managers, so their signature will be a the bottom with their pictures.

What do I need to change to make pictures show automatically ??

Is this DNS related?